# groovy if else not working properly

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a message on a slack server, respectively if a certain jenkins job finishes with "SUCCESS" then send a message, if the jenkins job fails then send another message. For some reason ony when the job finishes successfully the message is sent, if ti fails not message comes in slack

```
def testresult = currentBuild.currentResult       

if (testresult.equals("SUCCESS")) {

           slackSend(
                color: "#619b04",
                message: test1,
                token: "****",
                domain: "****",
                channel: "****"
                 )

        }else{

            slackSend(
                color: "#e2360f",
                message: "failed",
                token: "****",
                domain: "****",
                channel: "****"
                   )
              }
```

Is there something wrong with my sintax?

Comment: How do you handle exception? I guess the problem is that build is terminated before `if` statement. Please put the rest code of the job.

Comment: It's just a if else statement, if the jenking job is finishing successfully, "currentBuild.currentResult" will have the value SUCCESS and if not it will have the value FAILED. That's basically it

Comment: if job fails Jenkins will throw an exception and terminate your job before you can check `currentBuild.currentResult`. You need to catch the exception and only after this you can check `currentBuild.currentResult`

Comment: I cannot figure out which job status variable to use for this to get the real result. I presume that the "currentResult" will always show successful as the  job didn't finish

Answer (score 0):

When using *def* in Groovy, the actual type holder is Object (so you can assign any object to variables defined with def, and return any kind of object if a method is declared returning *def*).

This should work:

```
def testresult = currentBuild.currentResult
if (testresult.toString() == "SUCCESS") {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i set `if (testresult.equals("'SUCCESS'"))`

and then worked.